# How can I add a certain line form one output to a certain line from another output?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am having an issue with an output.

So I have this output from one command.

```
$ sudo /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -LdPdInfo -a0

Name               : Virtual_Disk0  
RAID Level         : 1 
State              : Optimal  
Number Of Drives   : 2  

Name               : Virtual_Disk1  
RAID Level         : 5 
State              : Optimal  
Number Of Drives   : 6  

Name               : Virtual_Disk2  
RAID Level         : 0 
State              : Optimal  
Number Of Drives   : 2
```

AND I have this second output from another command.

```
$ sudo /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -LdPdInfo -a0 \
> | xargs \
> | sed -r 's/(Slot Number:)(\s[0-9]+)/\2,/g' \
> | sed 's/(Target Id: .)/Physical Drives ids:/g'

Virtual Drive: 0 Physical Drives ids:  0,  1,
Virtual Drive: 1 Physical Drives ids:  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,
Virtual Drive: 2 Physical Drives ids:  8,  9,
```

So, I would like to combine the 2 outputs. The number at the end of Virtual Disk# must match the first number after the Virtual Drive: #

So, I want it to looks like this:

```
Name               : Virtual_Disk0  
RAID Level         : 1 
State              : Optimal  
Number Of Drives   : 2  
Virtual Drive: 0 Physical Drives ids:  0,  1,

Name               : Virtual_Disk1  
RAID Level         : 5 
State              : Optimal  
Number Of Drives   : 6  
Virtual Drive: 1 Physical Drives ids:  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,

Name               : Virtual_Disk2  
RAID Level         : 0 
State              : Optimal  
Number Of Drives   : 2 
Virtual Drive: 2 Physical Drives ids:  8,  9,
```

The entries always match, and they are in the same order.

I've tried this:

```
$ sudo /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -LdPdInfo -a0 ; \
> sudo /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -LdPdInfo -a0 | \
> xargs \
> | sed -r 's/(Slot Number:)(\s[0-9]+)/\2,/g' \
> | sed 's/(Target Id: .)/Physical Drives ids:/g'

Name               : Virtual_Disk0  
RAID Level         : 1 
State              : Optimal  
Number Of Drives   : 2  

Name               : Virtual_Disk1  
RAID Level         : 5 
State              : Optimal  
Number Of Drives   : 6  

Name               : Virtual_Disk2  
RAID Level         : 0 
State              : Optimal  
Number Of Drives   : 2 
Virtual Drive: 0 Physical Drives ids:  0,  1,
Virtual Drive: 1 Physical Drives ids:  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,
Virtual Drive: 2 Physical Drives ids:  8,  9,
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Do the entries always match? Are they always in the same order?

Comment: FYI: `\s` is a nonstandard extension. The standard syntax (which will work on more operating systems / with all POSIX-compliant versions of sed) is `[[:space:]]`.

Comment: Getting towards your question, though -- awk is a much better tool than sed for this job; it has proper variables that aren't a pain to work with and an execution model that generally makes more sense.

Comment: BTW, can you come up with a title that better reflects the technical problem you're trying to solve (and is generic enough to be helpful to other people)? Chances aren't very good that the next person trying to add "a certain line from one output to a certain line from another" will actually find this question useful, because one person's "certain line" is not another's. Our goal is to build a general-purpose, reusable knowledgebase, not to answer individual peoples' particular questions.

Comment: Please [edit] to add the output of **both** megacli commands to your question, so someone trying to test their answer doesn't need to have, or guess, your particular controllers.

Comment: (Right now you're repeating the same megacli command twice, but that can't possibly be right, because that command's stated output doesn't include `Slot Number` or `Target Id`, so none of your sed statements would match on it)

Comment: /me doesn't think we _need_ two files here; easy enough to manage output from two processes in-memory from a single shell.

Comment: Since `sudo /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -LdPdInfo -a0` produces the output shown in first block of text, and in the 2nd block youre piping it's output to `xargs` which will collapse all lines into a 1 and then you're piping that to 2 sed commands that are, as @CharlesDuffy mentioned, looking for strings `Slot Number:` and `Target Id:` that aren't present in that first block of text, you can't really be executing the commands you say you are. Please [edit] your question to show what you're REALLY trying to parse in that 2nd block, before running unnecessary xargs and 2 sed commands on it.

Comment: re: your latest update (`NEW UPDATE`) ... the 1st `sed` script does not generate the output you've provided but rather generates an error message (due to the space between the `/R '` and the `<(echo "$phyDrives3")`; the 2nd `sed` script (for me) *does* generate the desired output so not sure how your output is missing the lines from `$phyDrives3`

Comment: The time to make this kind of major edit is **before** there have been answers added to your question. Edits that invalidate preexisting answers are not welcome here; ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good morning.

```
$ sudo /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -LdPdInfo -a0 ; \

> sudo /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -LdPdInfo -a0 | \
> xargs \
> | sed -r 's/(Slot Number:)(\s[0-9]+)/\2,/g' \
> | sed 's/(Target Id: .)/Physical Drives ids:/g'
```

Adding a backslash at the end of a line to hide the newline doesn't combine outputs of separate commands. It's one long line of text to the parser, which still separated them with a semicolon as entirely separate operations.

As Charles and Ed have pointed out, your second command is identical to the first and can't be right. I suspect your second command (the one piped to xargs) is a copy/paste error. Please correct that.

---

That said, several people have already suggested a `<(cmd1) <(cmd2)` structure, which I also recommend.

Just as an alternate example, since I saved your outputs into `file` and `f2`, I'll use an otherwise awfully redundant UUoC to emulate the `<(...)`'s -

```
mapfile -t drive < <(cat f2)
while IFS=@ read -d@ block || [[ -n "$block" ]]
do echo "${block/\n/}${drive[ndx++]}"
done < <( sed 's/^$/@/' <(cat file) )
```

which outputs

```
Name               : Virtual_Disk0
RAID Level         : 1
State              : Optimal
Number Of Drives   : 2
Virtual Drive: 0 Physical Drives ids:  0,  1,

Name               : Virtual_Disk1
RAID Level         : 5
State              : Optimal
Number Of Drives   : 6
Virtual Drive: 1 Physical Drives ids:  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,

Name               : Virtual_Disk2
RAID Level         : 0
State              : Optimal
Number Of Drives   : 2
Virtual Drive: 2 Physical Drives ids:  8,  9,
```

The `awk` solutions are better, though, and I like Cyrus simple and elegant `sed` best for this.

## edit

```
$: sed /^Number/R<(echo "$phyDrives3") <(echo "$megaCliVD3")
Name               : Virtual_Disk0
RAID Level         : 1
State              : Optimal
Number Of Drives   : 2
Physical Drives    : 0,  1,
Name               : Virtual_Disk1
RAID Level         : 5
State              : Optimal
Number Of Drives   : 6
Physical Drives    : 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,
Name               : Virtual_Disk2
RAID Level         : 0
State              : Optimal
Number Of Drives   : 2
Physical Drives    : 8,  9,

$: mapfile -t drive < <(echo "$phyDrives3") && while read line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do echo "$line"; [[ "$line" =~ ^Number ]] && echo "${drive[ndx++]}"; done < <(echo "$megaCliVD3")
Name               : Virtual_Disk0
RAID Level         : 1
State              : Optimal
Number Of Drives   : 2
Physical Drives    : 0,  1,
Name               : Virtual_Disk1
RAID Level         : 5
State              : Optimal
Number Of Drives   : 6
Physical Drives    : 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,
Name               : Virtual_Disk2
RAID Level         : 0
State              : Optimal
Number Of Drives   : 2
Physical Drives    : 8,  9,
```

If you use that `bash` loop multiple times, just make sure you (re)initialize `ndx`.

Note that this can use here-strings instead of subshells:

```
$: mapfile -t drive <<< "$phyDrives3" && while read line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do echo "$line"; [[ "$line" =~ ^Number ]] && echo "${drive[ndx++]}"; done <<< "$megaCliVD3"
```

Comment: I rolled those changes back, because they violated the rules against question edits that invalidate preexisting answers.

Comment: Thank you for your help @paul-hodges mapfile worked for me, but I still have a doubt why the sed option doesnt work for me, that one looks cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

To simulate the `MegaCli64` outputs in my environment:

```
$ cat mega1.out
Name               : Virtual_Disk0
RAID Level         : 1
State              : Optimal
Number Of Drives   : 2

Name               : Virtual_Disk1
RAID Level         : 5
State              : Optimal
Number Of Drives   : 6

Name               : Virtual_Disk2
RAID Level         : 0
State              : Optimal
Number Of Drives   : 2

$ cat mega2.out
Virtual Drive: 0 Physical Drives ids:  0,  1,
Virtual Drive: 1 Physical Drives ids:  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,
Virtual Drive: 2 Physical Drives ids:  8,  9,
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
FNR==NR             { drives[$3] = $0; next }                  # 1st file: use 3rd field as index for storing entire line
$NF~/^Virtual_Disk/ { if (match($NF,/[0-9]+$/))                # 2nd file: last field starts with "Virtual_Disk"; look for number on end of last field and if found ...
                         driveno = substr($NF,RSTART,RLENGTH)  # extract said number
                    }
1                                                              # 2nd file: print current line
/^Number Of Drives/ { if (driveno in drives)                   # 2nd file: line starts with "^Number Of Drives"; if we have a matching record in the drives[] array then ...
                         print drives[driveno]                 # print said line to stdout and ...
                      driveno=""                               # clear our variable
                    }
' <(cat mega2.out) <(cat mega1.out)                            # NOTE: process 2nd set of MegaCli64 output *first*
```

This generates:

```
Name               : Virtual_Disk0
RAID Level         : 1
State              : Optimal
Number Of Drives   : 2
Virtual Drive: 0 Physical Drives ids:  0,  1,

Name               : Virtual_Disk1
RAID Level         : 5
State              : Optimal
Number Of Drives   : 6
Virtual Drive: 1 Physical Drives ids:  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,

Name               : Virtual_Disk2
RAID Level         : 0
State              : Optimal
Number Of Drives   : 2
Virtual Drive: 2 Physical Drives ids:  8,  9,
```

In OP's actual environment they'll want to make the following change:

```
# replace this:

' <(cat mega2.out) <(cat mega1.out)

# with this:

' <(sudo /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -LdPdInfo -a0 | xargs | sed ... | sed ... ) <(sudo /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -LdPdInfo -a0)
```

**NOTE:** I'm merely copying the `MegaCli64` commands and output provided by OP; OP will need to validate these commands and/or edit as needed

Comment: Out of curiosity -- which command generated mega2.out? (Rereading the question, the only argument set I see is `-LdPdInfo -a0`, which purportedly generates something in the style of  mega1.out)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree, the code provided by OP could not generate the 2nd set of output; I merely copied the 'output' provided by OP; I've update the `NOTE:` at the end of the question

Comment: I rolled those changes back, because they violated the rules against question edits that invalidate preexisting answers.

Answer (score 0):

Given these files (note specifically no leading blank lines...):

```
cat file1 
Name               : Virtual_Disk0  
RAID Level         : 1 
State              : Optimal  
Number Of Drives   : 2  

Name               : Virtual_Disk1  
RAID Level         : 5 
State              : Optimal  
Number Of Drives   : 6  

Name               : Virtual_Disk2  
RAID Level         : 0 
State              : Optimal  
Number Of Drives   : 2 

cat file2
Virtual Drive: 0 Physical Drives ids:  0,  1,
Virtual Drive: 1 Physical Drives ids:  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,
Virtual Drive: 2 Physical Drives ids:  8,  9,
```

You can use awk in [paragraph mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html) so that each block delimited by `\n\n` is a record and each line delimited with `\n` is a field:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; FS=OFS="\n"}
NR==1{split($0, line); next} # file2
{printf("%s\n%s\n\n", $0, line[FNR])}' file2 file1
```

Prints:

```
Name               : Virtual_Disk0  
RAID Level         : 1 
State              : Optimal  
Number Of Drives   : 2  
Virtual Drive: 0 Physical Drives ids:  0,  1,

Name               : Virtual_Disk1  
RAID Level         : 5 
State              : Optimal  
Number Of Drives   : 6  
Virtual Drive: 1 Physical Drives ids:  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,

Name               : Virtual_Disk2  
RAID Level         : 0 
State              : Optimal  
Number Of Drives   : 2 
Virtual Drive: 2 Physical Drives ids:  8,  9,
```

---

With your edit, given these files:

```
cat file1
Name               : Virtual_Disk0  
RAID Level         : 1 
State              : Optimal  
Number Of Drives   : 2  
Name               : Virtual_Disk1  
RAID Level         : 5 
State              : Optimal  
Number Of Drives   : 6  
Name               : Virtual_Disk2  
RAID Level         : 0 
State              : Optimal  
Number Of Drives   : 2 

cat file2
Physical Drives    : 0,  1,
Physical Drives    : 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,
Physical Drives    : 8,  9,
```

This awk:

```
awk '
NR==FNR{line[FNR]=$0; next} # file2
/^Number/{printf("%s\n%s\n", $0, line[++cnt]); next}
1' file2 file1
```

Prints:

```
Name               : Virtual_Disk0  
RAID Level         : 1 
State              : Optimal  
Number Of Drives   : 2  
Physical Drives    : 0,  1,
Name               : Virtual_Disk1  
RAID Level         : 5 
State              : Optimal  
Number Of Drives   : 6  
Physical Drives    : 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,
Name               : Virtual_Disk2  
RAID Level         : 0 
State              : Optimal  
Number Of Drives   : 2 
Physical Drives    : 8,  9,
```

Comment: @EdMorton-SOstopbullying: Doh! Thanks for you patient coaching.

Comment: @JosueBaquerizo: Similar. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

with ***ANY*** `awk` ( *assuming both inputs are already pre-sorted at the virtual drive level, and both files provide a perfect 1-to-1 mapping* ) :

> ```
> {m,g,n}awk '(_=FNR) == NR ? -(__[++_] = RS $!_ RS RS)\
>             : _<(_*_) ? ORS = __[_]   : (_)^(RS = "")'
> ```

```
 1  Name               : Virtual_Disk0  
 2  RAID Level         : 1 
 3  State              : Optimal  
 4  Number Of Drives   : 2  
 5  Virtual Drive: 0 Physical Drives ids:  0,  1,

 6  Name               : Virtual_Disk1  
 7  RAID Level         : 5 
 8  State              : Optimal  
 9  Number Of Drives   : 6  
10  Virtual Drive: 1 Physical Drives ids:  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,

11  Name               : Virtual_Disk2  
12  RAID Level         : 0 
13  State              : Optimal  
14  Number Of Drives   : 2 
15  Virtual Drive: 2 Physical Drives ids:  8,  9,
```

Comment: I rolled those changes back, because they violated the rules against question edits that invalidate preexisting answers.